# fabric-ca-server is not able to start with softhsm configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, softhsm

I have enabled the PKCS11 in fabric ca , but when starting the fabric-ca-server natively then throwing below error. Please note it works fine with default SW option.

1. Checkout the fabric-ca v1.3.0
2. Update BCCSP property as below

bccsp: 
    default: PKCS11 
    pkcs11: 
        library: /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so 
        pin: daily123 
        label: org1label 
        hash: SHA2 
        security: 256 
        filekeystore: 
            # The directory used for the software file-based keystore 
            keystore: msp/keystore

3. Run server with command 
   ./fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d

Error`2018/10/12 07:27:01 [INFO] Configuration file location: /opt/gopath/bin/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /opt/gopath/bin
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [INFO] Server Version: 1.3.0
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Making server filenames absolute
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Initializing default CA in directory /opt/gopath/bin
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Init CA with home /opt/gopath/bin and config {Version:1.3.0 Cfg:{Identities:{AllowRemove:false} Affiliations:{AllowRemove:false}} CA:{Name: Keyfile: Certfile:ca-cert.pem Chainfile:ca-chain.pem} Signing:0xc4204ce7d0 CSR:{CN:fabric-ca-server Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[safenet localhost] KeyRequest:0xc4204b1ac0 CA:0xc4204b1b40 SerialNumber:} Registry:{MaxEnrollments:-1 Identities:[{ Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Revoker:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.GenCRL:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.AffiliationMgr:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org2:[department1] org1:[department1 department2]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc4204de060 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL: CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile: IssuerSecretKeyfile: RevocationPublicKeyfile: RevocationPrivateKeyfile: RHPoolSize:1000 NonceExpiration:15s NonceSweepInterval:15m}}
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] CA Home Directory: /opt/gopath/bin
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Checking configuration file version '1.3.0' against server version: '1.3.0'
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:PKCS11 SwOpts:<nil> PluginOpts:<nil>}
2018/10/12 07:27:01 [DEBUG] Closing server DBs
Error: Failed to initialize BCCSP Factories: %!s(<nil>)
Could not find default`PKCS11`BCCSP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with latest fabric-ca images (as of now latest 1.4.0-snapshot-cb7353f).

Answer (score 0):

If you use fabric-ca 1.3 code base, follow below steps to make it work

```
GO_TAGS=pkcs11 make fabric-ca-server
```

update `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` with the softHSM data like token, label, pin, library (follow here https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/users-guide.html#configuring-fabric-ca-server-to-use-softhsm2)

restart fabric-ca server with `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw`

fabric-ca server is restarted as expected.